# What format does Bitmap.save save in vb.net?

Tags: bitmap

Just curious

How do we know that it'll save in jpg, png, rather than .bmp?

Comment: What about the documentation is not clear to you?

Comment: yes. I read the documentation. I didn't read the part where it's overloaded. So much for the negative vote :(

Comment: The documentation on the first overload (without parameters) is very clear. You still didn't explain what about it was unclear to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are overloads of the save() method that specify the format. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9t4syfhh.aspx for an example.

```
'Declaration
Public Sub Save ( _
    stream As Stream, _
    format As ImageFormat _
)
```

Comment: What happen if we do not specify the format? What will the default format be?

Comment: From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ktx83wah.aspx
"If no encoder exists for the file format of the image, the Portable Network Graphics (PNG) encoder is used."

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Image.Save Method (Stream, ImageFormat)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142147.aspx#Y0) or [Image.Save Method (String, ImageFormat)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9t4syfhh.aspx) to specify the format.